# Load remote URL in a div jquery

Tags: jquery, cross-domain

Does anyone know How can I load http://www.google.com in a div without an iframe or without creating body using jQuery ?

```
$("#div_id").load('http://www.google.com');
```

This does not work as it goes to cross-domain , and due to browser security , it does not allow the content to be placed at our div.

Thanks in advance

Comment: As you said, due to browser security it is not possible without an iFrame. You could try to use the API

Comment: @RobinvdA : May I know any API ?

Comment: Google's [Custom Search](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/) mabye suitable